# Erase whole array Python

Tags: python, arrays, erase

How do I erase a whole array, leaving it with no items?

I want to do this so I can store new values in it (a new set of 100 floats) and find the minimum.

Right now my program is reading the minimum from sets before I think because it is appending itself with the previous set still in there.  I use .append by the way.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Note that `list` and [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) are different classes.  You can do:

```
del mylist[:]
```

This will actually modify your existing list.  David's answer creates a new list and assigns it to the same variable.  Which you want depends on the situation (e.g. does any other variable have a reference to the same list?).

Try:

```
a = [1,2]
b = a
a = []
```

and

```
a = [1,2]
b = a
del a[:]
```

Print `a` and `b` each time to see the difference.

Comment: Really, there are arrays in Python? I did not know that. (Actually I probably knew but forgot) Anyway +1 for expanding on the difference between our answers. I just made a guess that the difference wouldn't matter for the OP.

Comment: i see. that helps

@david: yah, there's not much difference for me. but my newbness has gotten lessened :P

Comment: "arrays are different": not really, `del` works; see my answer

Comment: @John, I didn't mean `del` wouldn't work, just that lists and arrays are different.

Answer (score 34):

It's simple:

```
array = []
```

will set `array` to be an empty list. (They're called lists in Python, by the way, not arrays)

If that doesn't work for you, edit your question to include a code sample that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: This is how you re-initialize array if you are doing in a loop. This is fundamentally the right answer to the OP's question.

Comment: I prefer this approach as coming from a VBA background we use `array = ("")` so very similar and easy to rememeber! +1

Comment: This does not quite work. Consider the following code. 
```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
```
After this we have two senecios. 
1. a = []  # b == [1,2,3]
2. a.clear()  # b == []

Comment: @tcglezen That's using a different definition of "work" that was not part of the question.

Answer (score 9):

Well yes arrays do exist, and no they're not different to lists when it comes to things like `del` and `append`:

```
>>> from array import array
>>> foo = array('i', range(5))
>>> foo
array('i', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> del foo[:]
>>> foo
array('i')
>>> foo.append(42)
>>> foo
array('i', [42])
>>>
```

Differences worth noting: you need to specify the type when creating the array, and you save storage at the expense of extra time converting between the C type and the Python type when you do `arr[i] = expression` or `arr.append(expression)`, and `lvalue = arr[i]`

Comment: Far too few answers know the difference between a python `array` type and a python list.  +1 for you.

Comment: It is subtle, but it is important to say that if the list is in a hierarchy of objects, in certain cases we will lose its reference if we simply do `foo = []`, as we are defining a new list for "foo". For this reason an "up" for `del foo[:]`, because in this case we are modifying the originbal "foo" list. Thanks! =D

Answer (score 1):

Now to answer the question that perhaps you should have asked, like "I'm getting 100 floats form somewhere; do I need to put them in an array or list before I find the minimum?"

Answer: No, if `somewhere` is a iterable, instead of doing this:

```
temp = []
for x in somewhere:
   temp.append(x)
answer = min(temp)
```

you can do this:

```
answer = min(somewhere)
```

Example:

```
answer = min(float(line) for line in open('floats.txt'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python List clear() Method
*The clear() method removes all the elements from a list.*

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'orange']
fruits.clear()
print(fruits)
# outputs: []
```